# Get day name from datetime

Tags: python, datetime

How can I get the day name (such as Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, and Sunday) from a datetime object in Python?

So, for example, `datetime(2019, 9, 6, 11, 33, 0)` should give me `"Friday"`.

Answer (score 249, accepted):

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now.strftime("%A"))
```

See the Python docs for [datetime.now](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now), [datetime.strftime](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) and [more on strftime](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: Use `%a` for the abbreviated name

Answer (score 51):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime as date
>>> date.today().strftime("%A")
'Monday'
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using another package, you can also use pandas to achieve what you want:

```
>>> my_date = datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 6, 11, 33, 0)
>>> pd.to_datetime(my_date).day_name()
'Friday'
```

It does not sound like a good idea to use another package for such easy task, the advantage of it is that `day_name` method seems more understandable to me than `strftime("%A")` (you might easily forget what is the right directive for the format to get the day name).

Hopefully, this could be added to datetime package directly one day (e.g. `my_date.day_name()`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `import time` instead of `datetime` as following:

```
import time
WEEKDAYS = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

now = time.localtime()
weekday_index = now.tm_wday
print(WEEKDAYS[weekday_index])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
numdays = 7
base = datetime.date.today()
date_list = [base + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(numdays)]
date_list_with_dayname = ["%s, %s" % ((base + datetime.timedelta(days=x)).strftime("%A"),  base + datetime.timedelta(days=x)) for x in range(numdays)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an f-string along with a [format code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) such as `%A` or `%a`:

```py
> import datetime

# Provide a date object:
> d = datetime.date.today()
> d
datetime.date(2023, 2, 3)

# Provide a datetime object:
> dt = datetime.datetime.now()
> dt
datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 3, 17, 48, 7, 415010)

# Full weekday name:
> f'{d:%A}'
'Friday'
> f'{dt:%A}'
'Friday'

# Abbreviated weekday name:
> f'{d:%a}'
'Fri'
> f'{dt:%a}'
'Fri'
```

Note that the output strings are locale dependent. If requiring a locale independent comparison or even just a faster comparison, consider `date.weekday()` and `datetime.weekday()`.