# Date format to Day

Tags: python, date, days

Currently, I have a list of Date and time (2017-12-13 01:05:44) in my dataframe.
Can anyone please help me to create a new column ('Day') in my dataframe, with a list of days corresponding to my date columns.

*Can Ignore the time.

For example, the output:

```
Date, Day
2017-12-13 01:05:44, Wednesday  
2017-12-12 01:02:13, Tuesday
2017-12-11 01:00:55, Monday
2017-12-10 00:59:31, Sunday
2017-12-09 00:58:23, Saturday
```

[image]

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions because this is not a good question. This is not a code writing service, nor a read the docs and re-type them here for me service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get day name in datetime in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380389/how-to-get-day-name-in-datetime-in-python)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "gimme teh codez" / "do my work for me."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have date as strings then you have to convert them to datetime object

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

and layter you can use `Series.dt.weekday_name`

```
df['Day'] = df['Date'].dt.weekday_name
```

See: [timeseries - time date components](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-date-components) and [pandas.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)

---

Working example

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    "2017-12-13 01:05:44",
    "2017-12-12 01:02:13",
    "2017-12-11 01:00:55",
    "2017-12-10 00:59:31",
    "2017-12-09 00:58:23",
]

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date'])

print('\ntype before:\n', df.dtypes)

# convert strings to datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

print('\ntype after:\n', df.dtypes)

# get weekday name
df['Day'] = df['Date'].dt.weekday_name

print(df)
```

Result:

```
type before:
 Date    object
dtype: object

type after:
 Date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
                 Date        Day
0 2017-12-13 01:05:44  Wednesday
1 2017-12-12 01:02:13    Tuesday
2 2017-12-11 01:00:55     Monday
3 2017-12-10 00:59:31     Sunday
4 2017-12-09 00:58:23   Saturday
```