# Get the date name from a datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

Is it possible to get the name of a day (e.g. Monday) from a datetime object?

In my pandas dataframe I have a column of type datetime e.g.
      2016-07-01
and so on
I want to create a new column with the name of that day

Thanks in advance

Comment: `pd.to_datetime("2016-07-01").weekday_name` ?

Comment: @Rakesh notice `weekday_name` is deprecated, pandas suggests to use `pd.to_datetime("2016-07-01").day_name()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

duplicate of this? 
[How to get day name in datetime in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380389/how-to-get-day-name-in-datetime-in-python)

```
 import datetime
 now = datetime.datetime.now()
 print(now.strftime("%A"))
```

or:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime as date
>>> date.today().strftime("%A")
'Monday'
```