# Python coding: "Return a string stating the day of the week corresponding to datetime dt"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am Fairly new to coding and struggling with creating a sequence of code that will return a day of the week in text "e.g. 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'" that corresponds to a datetime dt. I have been told to store the day of the week string in a variable named 'str' and have been given this as an example:

`day_of_the_week(datetime(2019, 9, 6, 11, 33, 0))`
returns 'Friday'

`day_of_the_week(datetime(2000, 12, 25, 12, 0, 0))`
 returns 'Monday'

Comment: What is your question? Do you have some code you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get day name from datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380389/how-to-get-day-name-from-datetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below line of code would get you with day when you pass the date:

```
dt.strftime("%A")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`date.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) with the `'%A'` [format code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) which corresponds to the "weekday as locale's full name".

```
def day_of_the_week(dt):
    return dt.strftime('%A')
```

Examples

```
>>> day_of_the_week(datetime(2019, 9, 6, 11, 33, 0))
'Friday'
>>> day_of_the_week(datetime(2000, 12, 25, 12, 0, 0))
'Monday'
```