# How to get this week Monday 6 30 AM time?

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

Im running a python script that needs to get data since last Monday at 6:30 AM.

For example:

```py
if current time,2021/6/28(Monday) 15:00PM > required time is 2021/6/28(Monday) 06:30AM
if current time,2021/7/02(Friday) 15:00PM > required time is 2021/6/28(Monday) 06:30AM
```

How do I get this?

Comment: > To do this need to get last monday 6:30AM time

if you're replacing it at 6:30 every monday why do you need last monday?

Comment: @IanQuah Sorry I edited the question.Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380389/how-to-get-day-name-from-datetime) that could be a good starting point for your problem.

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now.strftime("%A"))
```

Output : 'Monday'

**EDIT :**

```
import datetime

days = {'Monday':7, 'Tuesday':1,'Wednesday':2,'Thursday':3,'Friday':4, 'Saturday':5, 'Sunday':6}
now = datetime.datetime.now()
current_day_name = now.strftime("%A")
date_threshold = now.replace(hour=18, minute=30, second=0)

#Handle case of datetime is monday and time is superiro to 6:30
if (current_day_name == 'Monday' and (now > date_threshold ) ):
    answer = now.replace(hour=18, minute=30, second=0)
else :    
    last_week = datetime.timedelta(days=days[current_day_name])
    answer = now - last_week
    answer = answer.replace(hour=18, minute=30, second=0)
    
print(answer)
```

This piece of code should do the trick.

Comment: No i need time of the last Monday. Not Just returning day String

Comment: Well, once you know what day it is. You can easily find the last monday (or next) with some calculation ( a bunch of if)